# How can I get an instance of my derived class using base class singleton?

Tags: c++, qt

I've made a base class that is used throughout multiple other classes. I'm expecting these other classes to be Singleton's. I was hoping to make the base class handle the getting and creating of the singleton, so that not everyone of the derived classes needed to implement a GetInstance function. Is this possible?

I'm working with QT, if that opens up any doors.

Here's my current code... In this example, I can't access PrintSomething(), because GetInstance returns an instance of BaseScriptCollection, I want it to somehow know to return the derived class (CustomScriptCollection in this case).

**BaseScriptCollection.h**

```
#ifndef BASESCRIPTCOLLECTION_H
#define BASESCRIPTCOLLECTION_H

#include <QObject>

class BaseScript;

class BaseScriptCollection : public QObject
{
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   explicit BaseScriptCollection(
         QObject *parent = nullptr);

   static BaseScriptCollection& GetInstance();


signals:

private:

};

#endif // BASESCRIPTCOLLECTION_H
```

**BaseScriptCollection.cpp**

```
#include "BaseScriptCollection.h"

BaseScriptCollection* s_pInstance;

BaseScriptCollection::BaseScriptCollection(
      QObject *parent) :
   QObject(parent)
{
   s_pInstance = this;
}

BaseScriptCollection& BaseScriptCollection::GetInstance()
{
   return *s_pInstance;
}
```

**CustomScriptCollection.h**

```
#ifndef CUSTOMSCRIPTCOLLECTION_H
#define CUSTOMSCRIPTCOLLECTION_H

#include <QObject>

#include "BaseScriptCollection.h"

class CustomScriptCollection :
      public BaseScriptCollection
{
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   explicit CustomScriptCollection(
         QObject *parent = nullptr);
   
   void PrintSomething();

signals:

};

#endif // CUSTOMSCRIPTCOLLECTION_H
```

**CustomScriptCollection.cpp**

```
#include "CustomScriptCollection.h"
#include "CustomScript.h"

CustomScriptCollection::CustomScriptCollection(
      QObject *parent) :
   BaseScriptCollection(parent)
{
   
}

void CustomScriptCollection::PrintSomething()
{
    qDebug("It worked!");
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>

#include "CustomScriptCollection.h"
#include "CustomScript.h"

void SomeOtherFunctionWithoutCustomScriptCollection()
{
   // Print Something is not accessible, because it returns as BaseScriptCollection...
   // I want it to somehow know it's a derived class and return the derived class (CustomScriptCollection).
   CustomScriptCollection::GetInstance().PrintSomething();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
#if QT_VERSION < QT_VERSION_CHECK(6, 0, 0)
   QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
#endif

   QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

   QQmlApplicationEngine engine;


   CustomScriptCollection script_collection;

   SomeOtherFunctionWithoutCustomScriptCollection();
   
   const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
   QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                    &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
      if (!obj && url == objUrl)
         QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
   }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
   engine.load(url);

   return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: mmm yes? `BaseClass::getInstance(int instanceId) { (...) if (instanceId== something) return correctDerivedInstance; (...) }` or what have you tried and had problem with?

Comment: yes it is possible, and there are endless number of ways to get something wrong. Don't let us guess but provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem

Comment: @pptaszni the problem is that it returns the BaseCollection instead of the derived collection... I've added code.

Comment: A singleton class with a public constructor? Hmm.... Can't you just cast your base class instance to the derived class?

Comment: Class template and the "Curiously Recursive Template Pattern" springs to mind. (Also, you can create any amount of your example classes, so they are not singletons.)

Comment: I can't use class templates as Qt doesn't support that for QObjects derived classes. Casting would work, but I'm trying to avoid the tediousness of needing to cast every time.

Answer (score 0):

I've templated the GetInstance method so that I can specify the returning class type and cast to it, but I'm curious if there is a better way (I'm thinking not without class templates, which I can't use due to QObject).

Here are the changes I made based on some of the feedback I've gotten...

**BaseScriptCollection.h**

```
#ifndef BASESCRIPTCOLLECTION_H
#define BASESCRIPTCOLLECTION_H

#include <QObject>

class BaseScriptCollection : public QObject
{
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   explicit BaseScriptCollection(
         QObject *parent = nullptr);

   template<typename T>
   static T& GetInstance()
   {
      return *qobject_cast<T*>(s_pInstance);
   }

signals:

protected:

private:

   static BaseScriptCollection* s_pInstance;
};

#endif // BASESCRIPTCOLLECTION_H
```

**BaseScriptCollection.cpp**

```
#include "BaseScriptCollection.h"

BaseScriptCollection* BaseScriptCollection::s_pInstance = nullptr;

BaseScriptCollection::BaseScriptCollection(
      QObject *parent) :
   QObject(parent)
{
   s_pInstance = this;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>

#include "CustomScriptCollection.h"
#include "CustomScript.h"

void SomeOtherFunctionWithoutCustomScriptCollection()
{
   // Ideally I don't need to specify a template parameter AND I don't need to declare a GetInstance function in every collection class...
   CustomScriptCollection::GetInstance<CustomScriptCollection>().PrintSomething();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
#if QT_VERSION < QT_VERSION_CHECK(6, 0, 0)
   QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
#endif

   QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

   QQmlApplicationEngine engine;


   CustomScriptCollection script_collection;

   SomeOtherFunctionWithoutCustomScriptCollection();

   const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
   QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                    &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
      if (!obj && url == objUrl)
         QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
   }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
   engine.load(url);

   return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: If you still have to specify the type every time, this is no better than casting.

Comment: You're right @JarMan, but it is less typing (less tedious)... Ideally I work out a way to not have to specify the type either. If I could declare GetInstance as a virtual pure function I think would even rather just override it in each collection, but statics cant.

Comment: Well, maybe you don't need to override a virtual function. You can just put GetInstance functions in all the derived classes anyway.

Comment: You're right @JarMan, I just did that. I can live with it being like this, just wish I could make the GetInstance definition a required pure function... but oh well. Thanks for the help.